# amp-story-grid-layer set to fill but image is cut off from the top and bottom

Tags: amp-html

I am using amp-story-grid-layer and setting the template to "fill". My background image is in the aspect ratio of 16:9 (1920 in height and 1080 in width). When I display the background in my amp-story-grid-layer, the top and bottom of the image is cut off by the viewing layout of the amp story. (~approximately 50 px is missing from the top and bottom )  Is AMP story suppose to be shown in 16:9? The story seems to have a width wider than 16:9.

Answer (score 1):

AMP stories are shown at the size of the user's browser window.  Although many phones are 16:9 (or, rather, 9:16 in the portrait orientation), some of that space is often taken by browser toolbars and the likes, leaving the effective available space less tall than 9:16.  And, of course, there are phones that were just not 9:16 to begin with.

On desktop or tablet landscape UIs, `amp-story` shows up to three `amp-story-page` elements at a time.  These are shown at a 3:5 aspect ratio (which is equivalent to 9:15; again, slightly shorter than 9:16).

In any case, you will need to be a bit flexible with having some part of the image cropped, in order for it to be truly full bleed.  Your options are:

- Change nothing; top/bottom of image will likely be cropped
- Use a wider aspect ratio for your images; left/right sides of image will likely be cropped
- Use `template="vertical"` for your layer, and `layout="responsive"` for your image, and center it with CSS; you will have [letterboxing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)) at the top/bottom of your image
- Use `template="vertical"` for your layer, and `layout="height-responsive"` for your image, and center it with CSS; you will have letterboxing at the left/right of your image
- Stretch the image, with 100% width and height; this will distort the appearance of your image

Unfortunately, for your UI to be responsive, you will need to choose which one of these scenarios suits you best.